# Pass parameter in BLoC pattern Flutter(Stream Controller)

Tags: flutter, enums, stream, bloc, sink

I am new to Flutter and not sure if this is the right method to follow. I am following YouTube tutorial to create a movie app using TMDB API and trying to pass 'genreId' from category.dart(comment below) to MovieBloc.dart. Is it possible to send the 'genreId'? If yes, how can I pass it? If not, what is the best way to do it?
Thank you

category.dart

```
final movieBloc = MovieBloc();

setState(() {
          selectedGenre = genre.id;
          movieBloc.eventSink.add(MovieControlAction.byGenre); // send genreId through here??
});
```

movie_bloc.dart

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter_api/Model/movie.dart';
import 'package:flutter_api/Service/api_service.dart';

enum MovieControlAction { fetch, delete, byGenre, }

class MovieBloc {
  final service = ApiService();
  final _stateStreamController = StreamController<List<Movie>>();

  StreamSink<List<Movie>> get _movieSink => _stateStreamController.sink;
  Stream<List<Movie>> get movieStream => _stateStreamController.stream;

  final _eventStreamController = StreamController<MovieControlAction>();
  StreamSink<MovieControlAction> get eventSink =>
      _eventStreamController.sink; //input
  Stream<MovieControlAction> get _eventStream =>
      _eventStreamController.stream; //output

  MovieBloc() {
    _eventStream.listen((event) async {
      if (event == MovieControlAction.fetch) {
        try {
          var movies = await service.getNowPlayingMovie();
          if (movies != null) {
            _movieSink.add(movies);
          } else {
            _movieSink.addError('Null');
          }
        } on Exception catch (e) {
          print(e);
          _movieSink.addError('Something went wrong');
        }
      } else if (event == MovieControlAction.byGenre) {
        var moviesByGenre = await service.getMovieByGenre(genreId);
        if (moviesByGenre != null) {
          _movieSink.add(moviesByGenre);
        } else {
          _movieSink.addError('Null');
        }
      }
    });
  }
  void dispose() {
    _stateStreamController.close();
    _eventStreamController.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it to the MovieBloc like follows:

```dart
final movieBloc = MovieBloc(genreId: genre.id);
```

And then create a constructor within the MovieBloc class:

```dart
class MovieBloc {
   final String genreId; // String, int, whatever type it is

   MovieBloc({
    required this.genreId,
   });
}
```

If you want to use a real Bloc, you should extend the MovieBloc like this:

```
class MovieBloc extends Bloc<MovieEvent, MovieState> {}
```

Currently it's not looking like you are using the actual Bloc pattern. Please check the [official Bloc documentation](https://bloclibrary.dev/). I promise - it's super helpful.